# Getting Value Passing a Key From a List of Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am given a list of lists, similar to the following.  I am very new to Python

```
[
{'id': 1244}, 
{'name': 'example.com'}, 
{'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
{'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
{'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain-overview.htm'}, 
{'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}, 
]
[
{'id': 1245}, 
{'name': 'example.com'}, 
{'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
{'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
{'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain-overview.htm'}, 
{'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}, 
]
[
{'id': 1246}, 
{'name': 'example.com'}, 
{'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
{'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
{'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain-overview.htm'}, 
{'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}, 
]
```

How can I get the "name" value from this, without having to nest loops?

My current code is:

```
for _row in _rs:
    print(_row)
    print(_row["name])
```

However, I am receiving an error message: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

So, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Because of the way the data is arranged, I don't believe you can accomplish this without nesting unless the `name` dict is always at the same index. The sub-lists are lists of single element dictionaries (not the most efficient!).

Comment: Are you sure you're having this format ? Can you paste the result of a print ?

Comment: btw you might want to look into the method "enumerate" in avoid the error you recived

Comment: yes @IMCoins that is the list, and yes I am sure

Comment: Currently what you are showing us is 3 lists of dictionaries, not a list of lists.

Comment: Oh... if I put `var = ` before what OP provided, it doesn't raise errors like on could expect (because there is missing brackets and commas) but instead it only takes the first list. Fun stuff. The other lists are calculated but assigned nowhere, just like typing `[ ]` or `" "` on a line doesn't do anything but is still accepted.

Comment: so... in example data shown, it is the result of: `print(_row)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it trully a list of list there is a comma between each list. then you can easily do that:

```
for i in x:
    print(i[1]['name'])
```

Comment: I would have to use the index for each individual item.  The issue is, I forsee them getting or being out of order... in otherwords, idx 1 may not always be "name".. hence why the need to select the items based on the key name

Comment: so use a nested loop instead

Answer (score 1):

How does this look?

```
l = [{'id': 1244}, {'name': 'example.com'}, ...]
names = e['name'] for e in l if 'name' in e]

print(names)
>>> ['example.com']
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Is this Python3 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move around the list and check if each dictionary has the "name" key, and print the result if yes.

```
list1 = [{'id': 1244}, 
         {'name': 'example.com'}, 
         {'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
         {'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
         {'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain-overview.htm'}, 
         {'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}]

for dictionary in list1:
    if "name" in dictionary.keys(): # Whether the dictionary looks like {"name": ...}
        print(dictionary["name"])
        break # Exit the loop now that we have the name, instead of going through the whole list.
```

**Edit:** your input is broken. Before being able to work on it, you want to change the function that gives you what you showed in the OP into that:

```
[ # <-- outer list starts
 [
 {'id': 1244}, 
 {'name': 'example.com'}, 
 {'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
 {'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
 {'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain- overview.htm'}, 
 {'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}, 
 ], # <--
 [
  {'id': 1245}, 
  {'name': 'example.com'}, 
  {'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
  {'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
  {'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain-overview.htm'}, 
  {'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}, 
 ], # <--
 [
  {'id': 1246}, 
  {'name': 'example.com'}, 
  {'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes'}, 
  {'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/'}, 
  {'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain-overview.htm'}, 
  {'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}, 
 ]
] # <-- outer list ends
```

Even better:

```
lists_of_dicts = [
                  [{'id': 1244, 
                    'name': 'example.com', 
                    'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes', 
                    'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/', 
                    'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain- overview.htm', 
                    'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}],

                  [{'id': 1245, 
                    'name': 'example.com', 
                    'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes', 
                    'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/', 
                    'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain- overview.htm', 
                    'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}],

                  [{'id': 1246, 
                    'name': 'example.com', 
                    'monitoring_enabled': 'Yes', 
                    'monitoring_url': 'http://www.example.com/', 
                    'monitoring_page_url': 'http://www.example.com/products-spool-chain- overview.htm', 
                    'monitoring_text_string': 'quality product'}]
                 ]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: Then your list is not formatted like mine. Can you make sure that the 3 lists of your example are correct? Are they 3 lists inside a larger one (in that case you'd need an extra pair of [ ])?

Comment: it is formatted like I posted it in the OP.  It contains 14,000 primary list items, each primary list item contains the inner-lists as I posted.  Should I really post the entire thing?

Comment: Can you show us how you would put the list of lists from the OP in a variable without raising errors? Because right now there is commas of brackets missing so it's hard to tell what your data structure is **exactly**.

Comment: @Kevin Is it `biglist = [ [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, ...], [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, ...], x14000 ]` ?

Comment: It is exactly as I posted it in the op.  Exactly.  No commas between the primary lists.   It appears to be coming from SQL, but its mashed up between 1 main query, and another details query that is `append`ing the details resultset to the primary resultset.

Comment: I think what I'm going to end up doing is writing a new sproc to get what is needed all in one recordset instead of this hacked together garbage...   this was an inherited project that I had nothing to do with initially...  i just hope I have permissions to be able to create another sproc